# How to match camel case identifiers with a Regular Expression?

Tags: c#, regex, camelcasing

I have the need to match camel case variables. I am ignoring variables with numbers in the name.

```
private const String characters = @"\-:;*+=\[\{\(\/?\s^""'\<\]\}\.\)$\>";
private const String start = @"(?<=[" + characters +"])[_a-z]+";
private const String capsWord = "[_A-Z]{1}[_a-z]+";
private const String end = @"(?=[" + characters + "])";

var regex =  new Regex($"{start}{capsWord}{end}", 
    RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant) }
```

This is great for matching single hump variables! But not with multiple nor does the one that meets the end of the line. I thought $ or ^ in my characters would allow them to match.

```
abcDef                                     // match 
notToday<end of line>                      // no match
<start of line>intheBeginning              // no match
whatIf                                     // match
"howFar"                                   // match
(whatsNext)                                // match
ohMyGod                                    // two humps don't match
```

I have also tried wrapping my capsWord like this 
 "(capsWord)+" but it also doesn't work.
WARNING! Regex tester online matches using this "(capsWord)+" so don't verify and respond by testing from there.

It seems that my deployment wasn't getting the updates when I was making changes so there may not have been an issue after all.

This following almost works save for the start of line problem. Note, I notice I didn't need the suffix part because the match ends with [a-z] content.

```
private const String characters = @"\-:;*+=\[\{\(\/?\s^""'\<\]\}\.\)$\>";
private const String pattern = "(?<=[" + characters + "])[_a-z]+([A-Z][a-z]+)+";

abcDef                                     // match 
notToday<end of line>                      // match
<start of line>intheBeginning              // no match
whatIf                                     // match
"howFar"                                   // match
(whatsNext)                                // match
ohMyGod                                    // match
```

So, if anyone can solve it let me know.

I have also simplified the other characters to a simpler more concise expression but it still has a problem with matching from the beginning of the line.

```
private const String pattern = "(?<=[^a-zA-Z])[_a-z]+([A-Z][a-z]+)+";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can  match an empty position between a prefix and a suffix to split the camelCase identifiers

```
(?<=[_a-z])(?=[_A-Z])
```

The prefix contains the lower case letters, the suffix the upper case letters.

---

If you want to match camelCase identifiers, you can use

```
(?<=^|[^_a-zA-Z])_*[a-z]+[_a-zA-Z]*
```

How it works:

```
(?<=                Match any position pos following a prefix exp    (?<=exp)pos
    ^               Beginning of line
    |               OR
    [^_a-zA-Z]      Not an identifier character
)
_*                  Any number of underlines
[a-z]+              At least one lower case letter
[_a-zA-Z]*          Any number of underlines and lower or upper case letters
```

So, it basically says: Match a sequence optionally starting with underlines, followed by at least one lower case letter, optionally followed by underlines and letters (upper and lower), and the whole thing must be preceded by either a beginning of line or a non-identifier character. This is necessary to make sure that we not only match the ending of a identifier starting with an upper case letter (or underscores and a upper case letter).

```
var camelCaseExpr = new Regex("(?<=^|[^_a-zA-Z])_*[a-z]+[_a-zA-Z]*");
MatchCollection matches = camelCaseExpr.Matches("whatIf _Abc _abc howFar");
foreach (Match m in matches) {
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
}
```

prints

```
whatIf
_abc
howFar
```

Comment: I miscommunicated my needs. I didn't actually need to split them but rather match them. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem today, what worked for me:

```
\b([a-z][a-z0-9]+[A-Z])+[a-z0-9]+\b
```

Note: this is for PCRE regexes

Explanation:

```
`(` group begin

`[a-z]` start with a lower-case letter

`[a-z0-9]+` match a string of all lowercase/numbers

`[A-Z]` an upper-case letter

`)+` group end; match one or more of such groups.
```

Ends with some more lower-case/numbers.
`\b` for word boundary.

In my case, the _camelCaseIdent_s had only one letter upper in between words.
So, this worked for me, but if you can have (or want to match) more than one
upper-case letter in between, you could do something like `[A-Z]{1,2}`